# The second java project created for Selenium webdriver dont invoke the firefox browser

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, log4j

This is strange:
I had one java project "A" in eclipse, where I created a automation framework using selenium webdriver 3.8. The test cases run without any issues on firefox & chrome.

I created another project "B" in eclipse where even a simple webdriver program to invoke a firefox browser and launching https://google.com don't work. If I copy and run this java program to project "A", there it works fine.

I get following error in project B:

```
1519377466493   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1519377466501   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:23459
Feb 23, 2018 2:47:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
1519377467110   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\ag1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.zR3DSF0kPKPE"
1519377469383   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
1519377470745   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
1519377478197   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 62067
1519377478784   Marionette  DEBUG   Register listener.js for window 4294967297
Feb 23, 2018 2:47:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Feb 23, 2018 2:47:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@a38d7a3, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@a38d7a3, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'EABYYA5G3S', ip: '16.166.226.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:259)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
    at pilot.Firefoxtest.main(Firefoxtest.java:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Feb 23, 2018 2:47:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
.
Feb 23, 2018 2:47:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Feb 23, 2018 2:47:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@a38d7a3, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@a38d7a3, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'EABYYA5G3S', ip: '16.166.226.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

The following points are clear from the error stack trace :

- **org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession** wasn't successful. Hence falls back to **OSS JSON Wire Protocol**.
- Falling back to original **OSS JSON Wire Protocol** fails too. Hence again attempts to fall back on **W3C remote end connection**.
- **org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException** is raised due to blank *required capabilities*

  ```
  required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
  ```
- *Selenium* version is not detected. (as `Build info: version: 'unknown'`)
- **GeckoDriver** not getting detecting back. (as `Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver`)

### Solution

The *Project Space* of **Project B** clearly appears to be **error-prone** due to indefinite/unknown reasons. It will be a better option to delete the entire *Project Space* and create a new *Project Space* to resume *Testing*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like for some reason the selenium jar i was using had some problem. I freshly downloaded selenium standalone jar, created a new project "B", copied rest of the project folders from "Project A". Now it worked without any issue.